# PowerShell Script Has Wrong Icon and Context Menu Items

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, windows-registry, context-menu

I have a .ps1 script on one of my computers and it looks like this:

[image]

When I right click and bring up the context menu, it has an "edit" entry.

However, when I copy the same PowerShell script over to one of my other computers, it looks like this:

[image]

and it does not have the "Edit" option as a context menu entry.

It seems like they have different system file associations, but I don't know how to change it. How to I make the 2nd example become like the first, where the description is "Windows PowerShell Script"? and it has the Edit context menu entry?

Comment: right click on the file, choose `open with`, then select `choose another app`, and finally pick such and tell the system to always use that app. [*grin*] ///// to avoid running PoSh scripts accidentally - which can be amazingly dangerous - the _default_ is to open the file in notepad. i changed mine to open the file in the ISE.

Comment: Have you tried to associate the script file with the PowerShell ISE? Are we talking about PowerShell 5 or PowerShell Core 7.2? Regardless, if you want the file association to be the same, you should export the applicable registry keys and import them on the second system.  I would of course make a backup of the current keys.  You can simply use "open with" to set the file association manually. The second machine as the file extension associated with the PowerShell prompt instead of the ISE.

Comment: @Ramhound, it is version 5.1 Which registry keys do I need to look at?

Comment: I don't have a machine I can look at the registry key, [this](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8703-restore-default-file-type-associations-windows-10-a.html#option2), has a registry key import you can use to associate the extension with Notepad.  You can easily modify it to launch PowerShell ISE instead.  I would just use "open with" instead and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

> How to I make the 2nd example become like the first, where the description is "Windows PowerShell Script"? and it has the Edit context menu entry?

You can export the registry key responsible association of an application on the .ps1 file extension.

An alternative method is to manually set the file extension association, through the "open with" menu and select PowerShell ISE, instead of `Windows PowerShell` which is the PowerShell prompt itself.

In either case you will have the same end result.